# no header added with addHeaderWriter in WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter

Tags: spring-security, header

I'd like to add a custom header in my Responses, but the following doesn't add anything to my responses:

```
@EnableWebSecurity
@Configuration
public class WebSecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

  @Override
  protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.headers()
        .addHeaderWriter(new StaticHeadersWriter("Salut","c'est Chico"));
  }
}
```

However I've followed Spring documentation: https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/html/headers.html

Thanks for your help !

PS: the debugger well enters in `addHeaderWriter()`

Comment: Ever solve this?